# If condition or try block

Tags: c#, .net

Which one is better to use?

```
if (condition)
{
    flagCheck = true;

    //Service layer call - code.

    flagCheck = false;
}
```

OR

```
if (condition)
{
    flagCheck = true;

    try
    {
       //Service layer call - code.
    }
    finally
    {
        flagCheck = false;
    }
}
```

What is the difference between the two methods? Are there situations where one can be used preferably more than other?

Comment: I would say the second option, cause it's always a good practice to catch errors

Comment: Would you use first one over second option in any case?

Comment: well if you don't call anything that could return an error. Something simple like calculations, I don't use try/catch. My reflex is to use try/catch when I call something that could be offline or when you read files and stuff like this. Because there's a high risk of causing errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first case, `flagCheck` remains `true` if `// Service layer call - code` throws an exception, while in the second case `flagCheck` will be set to `false` after `// Service layer call - code` regardless of whether an exception is thrown or not.

Neither of the two cases is inherently better than the other; pick the one that does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well a `try` block means you are looking to do a `dangerous` operation that needs to handled before allowing the program to crash.  Commonly the `if` statement in lieu of `try` is only for runtime exceptions.  I.E. NullReferenceException